# Limit application to one Facebook Page only

Tags: facebook, limit, addition

I'm currently building an application for my Facebook Page.

But how do I avoid that other people will add my application to their own page?
As far as I can see, they can easily use this link:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL
and find both my app_id and the server URL.

How do I avoid this?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
Tobias

Answer (score 3):

Parse the [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) – it tells you (amongst other things) what page id your app is loaded in. If this id is not yours – just give an error message, access denied or something like that.

Comment: +1. yes, this is the best way to see what page your application is running on.

Comment: CBroe: Thanks a lot! Just found this myself, but good to know that it's the right solution. :)